# What is a reasonable level of technology within an late medieval, early Renaissance-ish society? cameras versus saxophones

Tags: internal-consistency, technology

I must immediately confess that my co-writer and I have never settled on an official time period to base our world off of; it's a fantasy setting (with magic), and though there's fairly intricate armor and castles, and homes and literacy are normal things to have, it's widely accepted that the technology is not... sophisticated, I should say. I *can* tell you that we've decided there are no guns (which, if my memory doesn't fail me, puts it at earlier than the eighteenth century). At one point, there is the mention of someone playing a saxophone, which my co-writer did *not* approve of and retaliated with the existence of cameras (which I didn't approve of).

My question would be: in such a society where there's no modern transportation, roads, firearms... to what extent could I stretch technology? Would indoor plumbing be feasible? Initial cameras? Instruments like saxophones? Large ships? Coin and currency? What would lighting be like?

I'm fully aware of inconsistencies pre-existing within my story, I'm just curious as to what levels would still be believable, and wouldn't have a reader thinking "they have *that* but not *that*?"

Comment: Here is a [41 inch gun](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dardanelles_Gun) used in the siege of Constantinople in the 15th century, and again the British in the 19th. The Romans had indoor plumbing *in the antiquity*; their largest merchant ships (say, 2nd to 6th century CE) reached cargo capacities of 2,000 tons. Coins appeared around the 6th century BCE. A world without any *roads* is truly ancient, say around the time of the Trojan war. Saxophones and photocameras are basically contemporaneous, mid-19th century -- saxes need advanced fine mechanics, cameras need advanced optics and chemistry.

Comment: @AlexP  - I too was thinking that the story might be set in the Roman age,  They want civilization without guns.  Then I was thinking how much more I would like to read your answer than write one.  If you would be so kind...

Comment: Sorting the technological examples in chronological order: roads are older than the hills, think deep antiquity. Coins are old, but *much* more recent than roads, think pre-classical Greece. Indoor plumbing and large ships are late antiquity, think Roman Empire. Sophisticated armor and castles are medieval, think knights and courtly love. Guns are late medieval, think siege of Constantinople. Saxes and cameras are modern, think railroads, telegraphs and the American War of Secession.

Comment: Jerome Carcopino, [*Daily Life in Ancient Rome*](https://archive.org/details/dailylifeinancie035465mbp/page/n8/mode/2up), English translation 1943. Link goes to a free copy on Archive.org. I just don't know what to answer; do you want a synopsis of what technology they had in the 2nd century CE? What they *could* have had, but didn't for various reasons?

Comment: @Willk: Done as asked.

Comment: you can change saxo with trumpet to doot doot

Comment: Saxophones are actually quite possible at an early time frame. Somewhat simplified, mind, but entirely functional. [Saxie by Couesnon](https://tamingthesaxophone.com/product/couesnon-saxie)

Comment: @elemtilas: The [couesnophone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Couesnophone) was invented in 1924. The saxophone was invented in 1840, predating Couesnon's patent by 84 years.

Comment: @AlexP - I'm not sure what your point is.Mine is that saxophones are technologically feasible instruments centuries before the actual time of their invention.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suggest that you set the story in a world similar to the late Hellenistic world, that is, the Roman Empire from about the 1st to the 6th century CE. For a gentle introduction of how that world functioned, I recommend Jerome Carcopino's [*Daily Life in Ancient Rome*](https://archive.org/details/dailylifeinancie035465mbp/page/n8/mode/2up) (English translation 1943; the link goes to a free copy on Archive.org).

Going through the technologies mentioned in the question:

- *Fairly intricate armor:* check. Roman armor does not look like medieval armor, but it can be very sophisticated indeed.

  [image: Emperor Trajan in military armor]

  <sup>*Emperor Trajan in miliary armor; statue in Colonia Ulpia Trajana (modern [Xanten](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Colonia_Ulpia_Traiana), Germany). Photograph by [Hartmann Linge](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/User:Hartmann_Linge), available on Wikimedia under the Creative Commons Attribution License CC-by-SA 3.0. No, the emperor and his soldiers did no go barefoot; this is an example of artistic license. In real life, his mantle would be purple red (to show his rank as a superior officer), the cuirass and buttons would be polished metal. The strips protecting his loins would be leather.*</sup>
- *Castles:* sort-of check. The word "castle" comes from Latin *castellum* (a small fort), a diminutive of *castrum* (a fort). Roman forts did not look like medieval castles, but they could be large and sophisticated.

  Roman fortifications are a fascinating subject, which unfortunately vastly exceeds available time and space in the confines of a WB.SE answer.

  Here is a gate in the [Aurelian walls](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aurelian_Walls) of Rome itself (3rd century CE):

  [image: Porta Asinaria, outside] [image: Porta Asinaria, inside]

  <sup>*Porta Asinaria, a gate in the Aurelian walls of Rome, as it looks today. Left, seen from outside the walls; photograph by [Lalupa](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/User:Lalupa), available on Wikimedia, public domain. Right, seen from inside the walls; photograph by [3impact](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/User:3impact), available on Wikimedia under the Creative Commons CC0 1.0 Universal Public Domain Dedication.*</sup>

  See also: Roman [frontier fortifications](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limes_(Roman_Empire)) and the [Theodosian walls](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Walls_of_Constantinople#Theodosian_Walls) of Constantinople.
- *Homes and literacy are normal things to have*, part one, homes: check.

  *Of course* they had homes. They didn't live on the streets or in tents.

  Roman habitations come essentially in three varieties (excluding palaces and huts):

  1. Rich Romans had [villas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roman_villa) in the countryside. It was the dream of every Roman to accumulate enough money to build a villa and retire in luxury.

     [image: Scale model of a provincial Roman *villa rustica*]

     <sup>Scale model of a fairly typical provincial Roman *villa rustica*. Photograph by [Boksi](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/User:Boksi), available on Wikimedia under the GNU Free Documentation License, Version 1.2 or later.</sup>
  2. Rich and upper-middle-class Romans had [houses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domus) in the cities.

     [image: 19th-century artist's reimagining of an atrium in a Pompeian domus]

     <sup>*A 19th century artist's impression of an interior scene in a Roman house, showing the* [atrium](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atrium_(architecture)) *and the* [impluvium](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Impluvium) -- *that's the rain water basin; the opening in the roof is called the* compluvium. *Painting by [Luigi Bazzani](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luigi_Bazzani) (follow the link for more pictures of ancient subjects) in the American National Gallery of Art.*</sup>
  3. Ordinary Romans rented apartments in blocks of flats called [*insulae*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insula_(building)). Some *insulae* had up to nine storeys, but the usual was four or five. The construction codes (when respected) limited the height to 70 Roman feet (about 20 meters or 65 American feet). Better *insulae* had plumbing and running water, low-cost *insulae* didn't. (They were called *insulae* because they appeared as "islands" surrounded by alleys.)

     [image: Ruins of an insula]

     <sup>*Ruins of the uppermost two storeys of a Roman* insula. *Photograph by [Lalupa](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/User:Lalupa), available on Wikimedia, public domain.*</sup>
- *Homes and literacy are normal things to have*, part two, literacy: check.

  Most Romans could read and write, if usually somewhat poorly. Even a significant proportion of the slaves were expected to be able to read.

  How do we know this?

  - From popular comedy: in the comedy [*Pseudolus*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudolus) (*The Little Impostor*) by [T. Maccius Plautus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plautus), there is a scene (act I, scene 1) where a middle-class youngster, Calidorus, shows to his slave, the titular Pseudolus, a letter he had received from his lover, Phoenicium, a prostitute slave girl.

    > In the end, Phoenicium is, well, sort-of bought from her master Ballio and re-united with Caliodorus.

    (Seriously, it's a pretty good comedy. An English translation by Henry Thomas Riley, with copious notes, is [available at Perseus](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3atext%3a1999.02.0107). Highly recommended for getting a flavor of Roman life.)

    The point is, the *prostitute slave girl* wrote a letter. *The slave Pseudolus* is able to read it, and moreover he mocks the poor handwriting of the girl:

    > *Ut opinor, quaerunt litterae hae sibi liberos: alia aliam scandit. Has quidem pol credo nisi Sibulla legerit, interpretari alium posse neminem.*
    >
    > *As I think, these letters are very loving; they are climbing on each other's backs. I' faith, I really do believe that unless the Sibyl can read them, nobody else can possibly interpret them.*

    (H. T. Riley is gentle; the actual Latin says "those letters want to have children; they are mounting each other".)
  - From archaeological findings. We have many many many [graffiti](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roman_graffiti) scribbled on walls (at Pompeii, for example, or in the Roman catacombs) by low-class Romans. (Ancient Greeks did this too. Linguistis find those extremely informal inscriptions fascinating, because they reflect spoken language. They are one of the sources allowing us to know Latin and ancient Greek in *intimate* detail, hmmm, hmmm.)

    [image: "Dialogue" graffiti from Pompeii]

    <sup>*"Dialogue" graffiti from Pompeii. Two hands; the upper lines read:* "Successus the weaver loves Iris, the slave girl of the inn keeper; she doesn't care about him, but he prays she takes pity on him; a rival wrote this, hello!". *The lower lines are the response:* "you are so jealous you're bursting; don't try to barge in on someone who is more handsome, and who is a most wicked and charming man". *Yes, that's how Roman handwriting looked like. Note that the grammar and spelling are quite bad, definitely not standard Latin, showing that the two men were poorly educated. Reproduction by [Fer.filol](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/User:Fer.filol), available on Wikimedia, public domain.*</sup>
- *There are no guns:* check. Guns became available in the High Middle Ages, and became *useful* in battle towards the end of the Middle Ages.
- *Saxophones:* no way. Saxophones are *very* modern musical instruments; they need highly advanced fine mechanics and resonably advanced metallurgy. In general, musical instruments with valves are modern, as in post-Renaissance. They just didn't have the industrial base to make them earlier. In real history, Adolphe Sax invented the saxophone in the 1840s.
- *Photographic cameras:* no way. Need both advanced optics (as in, at least 18th century) and advanced chemistry. Photographic cameras appeared in the first half of the 19th century.
- *No modern transportation:* well, duh. It's the Roman Empire. Nothing is "modern" by definition. But they did have extensive transportation networks, ran a good imitation of a global economy (within the limits of their world, of course), traded with distant India (and, through Indian intermediaries, with China). People did travel for business and pleasure over long-ish distances -- think about the [*Acts of the Apostles*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acts_of_the_Apostles) in the New Testament, for example. They even had tourists...
- *Roads:* the Romans had an extensive network of roads. Quite famous for it, in fact. If you want a world without roads you must go down in time to the pre-history.
- *Indoor plumbing:* yes, rich Romans had indoor plumbing. Poorer Romans had access to public toilets and public baths.
- *Large ships:* check. As I said, the Romans ran a pretty convincing imitation of a globalized economy, within the limits of their world. Large merchant ships reached capacities of 2,000 tons. Those were sailing ships, of course; no practical motors of any kind were available.
- *Coin and currency:* check. Coins appeared in the late 7th or early 6th century BCE. The Romans even had a decent financial system, for the antiquity. There were contracts, there were bankers, there were letters of credit.
- *Lighting:* well, other than the Sun, they had candles, and torches, and lamps. Ordinary indoor lighting at night used oil lamps (burning olive oil), like this:

  [image: Indian oil lamp]

  <sup>*A contemporary Indian oil lamp, very similar to what the Romans used. Photograph by [Arne Hückelheim](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/User:Knipptang), available on Wikimedia under the GNU Free Documentation License, Version 1.2 or later.*</sup>

  There were cheap unglazed lamps with one wick, like the one in the photo, and expensive glazed lamps with multiple wicks.

  Outdoor lighting used torches; there was *very* little fixed outdoor lighting; everybody who was rich enough and went out at night had servants with torches to illuminate the path.

Other technological and artistic or decorative elements of civilization which you may find interesting about the late Hellenistic or Roman world:

- [Mosaic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mosaic#Greek_and_Roman) was a decorative technique used on a very large scale.
- They painted their walls [al fresco](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fresco); all well-to-do Romans had painted walls in their houses; [example 1](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Herkulaneischer_Meister_002.jpg), [many examples 2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Villa_of_the_Mysteries), all from Pompeii.
- They made numerous very realistic and beautiful potraits, both [painted](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fayum_mummy_portraits) and [sculpted](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roman_portraiture); we *know* how many famous Romans looked like, and if we wanted we could show them accurately in movies.
- They used a very ingenious [system of central heating](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypocaust), circulating hot air below the floors of rooms.

There are quite a few successful series of novels set in the Roman world, with or without transposing modern concepts. For example, you may want to read some of the books in the [Marcus Didius Falco](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marcus_Didius_Falco) series by [Lindsey Davis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lindsey_Davis); M. Falco is a private investigator-and-troubleshooter employed by emperor [Vespasian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vespasian), and moves around in a pretty much accurate Roman society.

Comment: Excellent!  It took a long time to read because I kept exploring links,  I did not know the Roman walls were used until so recently!  I did not know any major European city used its ancient walls up until recent times.